# Нужен список стилей для QDial (PyQt)

Tags: python, pyqt, qss, paintevent, qdial

Помогите пожалуйста, работаю с библиотекой *PyQt* в *Python*. Мне нужны все виды `Stylesheets` для обьекта `QDial`. 
Поискал в документации, там никаких упоминаний стилей для `QDial` не нашел. 
Если конкретно мне нужно изменить цвет рисок на красный и в целом хочу его кастомизировать для приложение с потоковым радио.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, разработчики не уделяли должного внимания `QDial`, так как это редко используемый виджет, который трудно реализовать для индивидуального использования. 
Таким образом, он не поддерживает многие функции внешнего вида,
а также не имеет конфигурации таблицы стилей.

Если вы хотите изменить внешний вид `QDial`,
единственная безопасная возможность - создать его подкласс,
переопределить его `paintEvent()` и нарисовать его самостоятельно.

Как вариант, выглядит это примерно так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class ValueDial(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    _dialProperties = (
        'minimum', 'maximum', 'value', 'singleStep', 'pageStep',
        'notchesVisible', 'tracking', 'wrapping', 
        'invertedAppearance', 'invertedControls', 'orientation')
    _inPadding = 3
    _outPadding = 2
    valueChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # удалить свойства, используемые в качестве аргументов 
        # ключевого слова для циферблата
        dialArgs = {k:v for k, v in kwargs.items() if k in self._dialProperties}
        for k in dialArgs.keys():
            kwargs.pop(k)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.dial = QtWidgets.QDial(self, **dialArgs)
        layout.addWidget(self.dial)
        self.dial.valueChanged.connect(self.valueChanged)
        # сделать dial прокси-сервером фокуса (чтобы он перехватывал фокус 
        # и key events)
        self.setFocusProxy(self.dial)

        self.value = self.dial.value
        self.setValue = self.dial.setValue
        self.minimum = self.dial.minimum
        self.maximum = self.dial.maximum
        self.wrapping = self.dial.wrapping
        self.notchesVisible = self.dial.notchesVisible
        self.setNotchesVisible = self.dial.setNotchesVisible
        self.setNotchTarget = self.dial.setNotchTarget
        self.notchSize = self.dial.notchSize
        self.invertedAppearance = self.dial.invertedAppearance
        self.setInvertedAppearance = self.dial.setInvertedAppearance

        self.updateSize()

    def inPadding(self):
        return self._inPadding

    def setInPadding(self, padding):
        self._inPadding = max(0, padding)
        self.updateSize()

    def outPadding(self):
        return self._outPadding

    def setOutPadding(self, padding):
        self._outPadding = max(0, padding)
        self.updateSize()

    # следующие функции необходимы для корректного обновления layout
    def setMinimum(self, minimum):
        self.dial.setMinimum(minimum)
        self.updateSize()

    def setMaximum(self, maximum):
        self.dial.setMaximum(maximum)
        self.updateSize()

    def setWrapping(self, wrapping):
        self.dial.setWrapping(wrapping)
        self.updateSize()

    def updateSize(self):
        # функция, которая устанавливает поля, 
        # чтобы в строках значений всегда было достаточно места
        fm = self.fontMetrics()
        minWidth = max(fm.width(str(v)) for v in range(self.minimum(), self.maximum() + 1))
        self.offset = max(minWidth, fm.height()) / 2
        margin = self.offset + self._inPadding + self._outPadding
        self.layout().setContentsMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin)

    def translateMouseEvent(self, event):
        # вспомогательная функция для перевода событий мыши на dial
        return QtGui.QMouseEvent(event.type(), 
            self.dial.mapFrom(self, event.pos()), 
            event.button(), event.buttons(), event.modifiers())

    def changeEvent(self, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.FontChange:
            self.updateSize()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.dial.mousePressEvent(self.translateMouseEvent(event))

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.dial.mouseMoveEvent(self.translateMouseEvent(event))

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.dial.mouseReleaseEvent(self.translateMouseEvent(event))

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        radius = min(self.width(), self.height()) / 2
        radius -= (self.offset / 2 + self._outPadding)
        invert = -1 if self.invertedAppearance() else 1
        if self.wrapping():
            angleRange = 360
            startAngle = 270
            rangeOffset = 0
        else:
            angleRange = 300
            startAngle = 240 if invert > 0 else 300
            rangeOffset = 1
        fm = self.fontMetrics()

        # опорная линия, используемая для цели текстового прямоугольника
        reference = QtCore.QLineF.fromPolar(radius, 0)\
            .translated(self.rect().center())
        fullRange = self.maximum() - self.minimum()
        textRect = QtCore.QRect()

        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        qp.setRenderHints(qp.Antialiasing)
        for p in range(0, fullRange + rangeOffset, self.notchSize()):
            value = self.minimum() + p
            if invert < 0:
                value -= 1
                if value < self.minimum():
                    continue
            angle = p / fullRange * angleRange * invert
            reference.setAngle(startAngle - angle)
            textRect.setSize(fm.size(QtCore.Qt.TextSingleLine, str(value)))
            textRect.moveCenter(reference.p2().toPoint())
            penColor = QtGui.QColor("#A52A2A")
            qp.setPen(QtGui.QPen(penColor, 2))
            qp.drawText(textRect, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, str(value))

            self.distance = 10
            self.center = self.rect().center() + QtCore.QPoint(1, 1)
            fullExtent = radius + self.distance
            line = QtCore.QLineF.fromPolar(radius-12, 240 - angle)
            line.translate(self.center)
            penColor = QtGui.QColor("#F00")
            qp.setPen(QtGui.QPen(penColor, 2))
            qp.drawLine(line)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 10, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    dial = ValueDial(minimum=1, maximum=11)
    dial.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @aart17 пожалуйста.